# Translate MessageDialog (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have this
`var dialog = new MessageDialog("Error", "Error: Example");
await dialog.ShowAsync();`
In XAML I translate like this: x:Uid="Example"
I want to translate the messages you present in messagedialog
How do I do translations in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `ResourceLoader` class:

```
string localizedString = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("<Key from resw>");
```

You can pass an optional string to the `GetForCurrentView` method where you can specify the resw file's name.

**UPDATE**

The `GetString` method returns a string object what you can use to create `MessageDialog`.

```
var loader = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView();
string title = loader.GetString("example_Title"); 
string content = loader.GetString("example_Content"); 
var dialog = new MessageDialog(content, title);
await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

**UPDATE 2**

The key in the resw file cannot contains '.' character for some reason. Maybe because the x:Uid behavior...

Comment: I put this code in my C # where I want to translate right?
And then how do I do it in the .resw file?

Comment: yes you can use this in your C# file were you want to translate and your resw file is look like the same as you are using `x:Uid`. You pass the Uid key to the `GetString` method.

Comment: I have this in my C# file: (example is my Uid)
`string localizedString = ResourceLoader.GetForCurrentView().GetString("example");
var dialog = new MessageDialog("", "");`
And in the .resw I have this: example.Content and example.Title anda the translates but dont work, dont appears anything

Comment: Thank you very much! I already understood, but it still does not work, everything appears blank, with nothing written :(

Comment: Where is your resw file?

Comment: In this folder: Strings/en-US/resources.resw

Comment: OK I will investigate on this

Comment: I found it: the . (dot) character in the key is the bad guy.

Comment: Thank you very much, but unfortunately this does not solve the problem. Everything is still blank, everything is empty

Comment: My sample code is working, can you provide your code (C# + resw)?

Comment: Thank you so much,it works! The mistake was mine. In the .resw file, I had not updated, had example.title and example.content. Just corrected and solved the problem, thank you very much!